# Programatically tell eclipse to open source code and go to specific line

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

Is there anyway to programatically tell eclipse to open a *.java file and go to specific line?  I'm writing a swing program which is able to launch another java program (as a separate process). I redirect to output stream of the external program to a text pane. Some of the external programs print stack traces. I want the text pane to display the stack trace the way eclipse console does (make the Classname.java:234 hyperlink, and if I click on the link, it opens the file in eclipse and directly go to that line).

If possible I don't want to create any dependencies to any eclipse classes.

Comment: Wouldn't you have to use the Eclipse API in order to tell it to open the file and navigate to the specific line?

Comment: Can't I use something like `Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)` if I associate *.java file with Eclipse?

Comment: ...and "go to [a] specific line"?

Comment: That I don't know yet ...